# How To Scroll Through A Group Of Label Widgets In Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, scrollbar

I'm creating a quiz in Tkinter and am currently working on a frame to display records from an SQLite database which I would like to show in a 'table' format. I have already created a group of labels which will act as my 'table' but haven't been able to implement a scrollbar successfully.

I understand the scrollbar doesn't work directly with the frame and that I need to create a canvas and attach all widgets to this. I have attempted to work through some of the solutions given on the forum but can't integrate them with my own code properly. At the moment, the scrollbar I have created isn't functional.

```py
class Progress(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.___init__(self, parent)
        frametwo = Frame(self) #creates a secondary frame for the canvas?
        frametwo.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        #attempts to create a functional scroll bar
        text_area = tk.Canvas(frametwo)
        vscroll = tk.Scrollbar(text_area, orient="vertical", command = text_area.yview)
        text_area['yscrollcommand'] = vscroll.set
        text_area.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        vscroll.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky="nsew")
        text_area.configure(scrollregion = text_area.bbox("all"))

        #creates the label widgets
        self._widgets = []; columns = 6
        for row in range(0,11):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(columns):
                label = tk.Label(text_area, text="%s/%s" % (row, column), 
                                 borderwidth=0, width=10, height =2 )
                label.config(bg = "White", font=("Calibri bold", 20))
                label.grid(row =(row+2), column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                current_row.append(label)
            self._widgets.append(current_row)

        for column in range(columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
```

Sorry if the code is unclear/inefficient, I'm very much a beginner using tkinter! The code above outputs my labels in the manner I want & places a scrollbar alongside them, but it has no functionality and won't move to show the remaining widgets. I'm sure I've made a basic error or omitted some code. How would I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make another frame within your `canvas` and then use `canvas.create_window` to create the frame. The label widgets should go inside that frame.

```
class Progress(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        frametwo = tk.Frame(self) #creates a secondary frame for the canvas?
        frametwo.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        #attempts to create a functional scroll bar
        canvas = tk.Canvas(frametwo)
        canvas_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
        vscroll = tk.Scrollbar(frametwo, orient="vertical", command = canvas.yview)
        canvas['yscrollcommand'] = vscroll.set
        canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        vscroll.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky="nsew")

        #creates the label widgets
        self._widgets = []; columns = 6
        for row in range(0,11):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(columns):
                label = tk.Label(canvas_frame, text="%s/%s" % (row, column),
                                 borderwidth=0, width=10, height =2 )
                label.config(bg = "White", font=("Calibri bold", 20))
                label.grid(row =(row+2), column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
                current_row.append(label)
            self._widgets.append(current_row)

        for column in range(columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=canvas_frame, anchor='nw')
        canvas_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"),width=450,height=300))
```